# How to consume the o/p of a procedure with result view in HANA

Tags: hana

Is it possible to assign the o/p of a procedure, with result view, to a temp table in procedure. Please advise how can this be done. Thanks.

Comment: Clarify what does "o/p" stand for, please... I often feel in a JOA (jungle of acronyms) where people say "HMHAY" for "Hello mate, how are you?" :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
INSERT INTO temp_table
(SELECT * FROM view_name);
```